# In c# what does this mean (m => m.Title)

Tags: c#, lambda

I am new to MVC (c#) and do not know some of the uses of what looks like an arrow or
a comparison operator.  I can not tell what it means.

I have seen this used in many areas in MVC (c#)

What does `=>` stand for?  Is it an arrow or is it a comparison operator?

Example 1:

```
return storeDB.Albums.Orderby(a => a.Price)
```

Example 2:

```
.ForEach(a => context.Albums.Add(a));
```

Example 3:

```
bool isValid = storeDB.Orders.Any(o => o.OrderId == id && o.Username == User.Identity.Name);
```

Example 4:

```
var addedAlbum = storeDB.Albums.Single(album => album.AlbumId == id);
```

Example 5:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
```

Please explain in simple terms to understand.  Thanks.

Comment: You should probably learn C# first, before getting into ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: It's hard to know how to explain lambda expressions to you without knowing how familiar you are with C#. Do you have a background in Java or any other OO language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) - short-cut for creating [anonymous methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (i.e. delegates). Operator `=>` is a `goes to` operator. Which separates anonymous method parameters from anonymous method body.

---

```
storeDB.Albums.Orderby(a => a.Price)
```

Here we have anonymous method which accepts album as a parameter. This album goes to body, which returns value of album's `Price` property. Same with delegate syntax:

```
delegate(Album a) { return a.Price; }
```

Or with named method:

```
private decimal GetAlbumPrice(Album a)
{
    return a.Price;
}
```

As you can see, lambda expression syntax is the shortest form for achieving same result.

Answer (score 0):

you should read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx .

Lambdas in simple terms are basically anonymous functions that can be used to create delegates or expression types. It is basically a convenient shorthand for writing delegates ( this is too simplistic a way to put it though )